# How to serialize Object with nested lists to JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, serialization

I want to create JSON from an object containing nested ArrayLists.

#### Object structure

1. An object `Subject` containing a list of `Test`s.
2. Each `Test` contains a list of `Question`s.
3. Each `Question` finally contains the object `AnswersContent`.
4. This final object `AnswersContent` contains 4 separate `String`s (answerA, answerB, answerC, answerD).

#### Source

```java
public class Subject {

  private ArrayList<Test> tests = new ArrayList<Test>();
  //some other fields (String, int)
}
```

```java
public class Test {

  public ArrayList<Question> test = new ArrayList<Question>();
  // some other fields (String, int)
}
```

```java
public class Question {

  private AnswersContent answersContent;
  // some other fields (String, int)
}
```

```java
public class AnswersContent {

  private String answerA;
  private String answerB;
  private String answerC;
  private String answerD;
}
```

So I've got nested lists of objects.
I don't know how to get JSON from it and what tool I could use.

Maybe I just searched using the wrong phrases.

Comment: Take a look at this: [JSON in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-json).

Comment: I like gson. It's pretty straight forward.

Comment: Most of popular JSON libraries (e.g. `Jackson`, `Gson` and `org.json`) can achieve this, you can first study "How to convert Object to JSON".

Comment: Since you got some library recommendations already, did you try to use them? Then, please [edit] your question and post your attempt (_to get JSON out_) as [example]! On this basis we can guide you.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public String getAsJsonString(){
     return new Gson().toJson(this);
}
```

you must add this method to the "AnswersContent" class;

You can also download [Gson jar file](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/), or if you are using [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson) add it to your pom.xml

see also the [User Guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md)

Comment: Just posting code-snippets is a good start. It's always helping to explain the solution. Especially when introducing new libraries (like `Gson` here) a link may help to download or get started.